# LINEで送信した内容をX（旧Twitter）の下書きに保存したい

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, twitter, webapi, line

#### 実現したいこと

LINEから送信した内容を、X（旧Twitter）の下書きに保存する

#### 前提

LINE Messaging API、Twitter API、GASを使ってLINE上で
X（旧Twitter）にポストできるようなシステムを作成しています。

APIを取得後、いざGASでコードを書く際にエラーが発生してしまいました。
（Bardを参考に作成したコードなので、どこかが上手くいっていない可能性はあります。）
実際に下書きに保存することは可能なのかも見ていただきたいです。

#### 現状で発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
構文エラー: SyntaxError: Unexpected string 行: 34
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
function saveDraft(text) {
  // TwitterAPIの設定
 //　スクリプトプロパティを使用しています。
  const CONSUMER_KEY = "CONSUMER_KEY";
  const CONSUMER_SECRET = "CONSUMER_SECRET";
  const ACCESS_TOKEN = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
  const ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET";

  // LINEAPIの設定
  const CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN = "CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN";

  // 下書き保存APIのURL
  const DRAFT_SAVE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/drafts/create";

  // LINEから受信したメッセージの取得
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/receive",
    {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    }
  );
  const message = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  // 下書きを保存する
  const data = {
    "text": text,
  };
  const text_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    DRAFT_SAVE_URL,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}:{ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }
  );
  return response.getResponseCode();
}

// メイン処理
function onMessage(event) {
  const text = event.message.text;
  const status = saveDraft(text);
  console.log(status);
}

// トリガーの設定
onMessage();
```

#### 試したこと

https://n-mukineer.com/2022/11/25/tweet-from-line/
上記のサイトを参考にアレンジしたのですがうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: 一見して構文エラーを出しそうなのは、`f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}:{ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}"` の部分です。Pythonのf-string（フォーマット済み文字列リテラル）風の構文に見えますが、これはJavaScriptでは使えません。ここが指摘されている34行目なのかは分かりませんが、まずはこれを直してみるとよいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。fを消し実行したところ、

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')　行:42`

とのエラーメッセージが表示されました。

Answer (score 2):

エラーが指している部分は

```js
"Authorization": f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}:{ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}",
```

の部分かと思います．

おそらく文字列に変数の値を埋め込みたいのだと推測しますが， JavaScript ではこの方法では埋め込みできません．

素直に文字列結合するか，もしくはバッククォートを使って埋め込みができます．

```js
`Authorization ${ACCESS_TOKEN}:${ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}`
```

みたいな感じです

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。埋め込みをやめ実行したところ、

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')　行:42

とのエラーメッセージが表示されてしまいました。

Comment: onMessage() の実行でエラーになっているんだと思います．引き数 event の message プロパティにアクセスしようとしていますが，おそらく message というプロパティは存在しません．このスクリプトがどのようなトリガーで実行されるものかこれを見ただけではわかりませんが，引き数 event には GAS の Event Object が入ってきます．https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?hl=ja を見てみると，どのようなプロパティがあるか確認できますので参考までに．